# eval() alternative in Meteor to a variable name declaring a Mongo collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor code has `let Vehicles= new Mongo.Collection('vehicles');` and a html `<div id='Vehicles'`, I like use the `<get obj in var named Veh>.find({}).count()`  the below code works fine but I read to avoid the use of `eval()`. Reading up on alternatives could not satisfy me to formalize a solution. Please help with a solution or show how to write this in a non `eval()` way. Thanks

**Update: It needs to run on the server "nodeJs" and not in the browser**

```js
//cliant/main.js

  $('input').on('blur', function(e) {
    let collectionVar= $(this).parents('div')[2].id    // Vehicles is the same as the collection variable.
    console.log(eval(collectionVar).find({}).count())   // works but need an alternative to eval()

  })
```

```html
<template name="Vehicles">
  <div id="Vehicles" class="subject-container" >

    <div class="section-head">
      <div class="control">

        <input id="plate" type="text" size="6" placeholder="plate" value={{vehicle.plate}}>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What's the value type of sectionId? Can you give an example?

Comment: I changed "selectionId" to "collectionVar" for clarity. The value it has is "Vehicles" which is the same as the collection variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Template events instead of jQuery event listeners to get the most out of your data during UI events.

You can then easily attach `data-*` attributes to the component to avoid any `parent` fiddling:

```html
<template name="Vehicles">
  <div id="Vehicles" class="subject-container" >

    <div class="section-head">
      <div class="control">

        <input id="plate" 
           data-collection="Vehicles" <!-- ref the collection -->
           type="text" 
           size="6" 
           placeholder="plate" 
           value={{vehicle.plate}}>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

You can then use either a global Object, that references collecitons by name or `dburles:mongo-collection-instances` to get the collection by name (I would favour the second, because it does not further pollute the global namespace):

```js
Template.Vehicles.events({
  'blur #plate' (event, templateInstance) {
    const collectionName = templateInstance.$(event.currentTarget).data('collection')
    // wihtout jQuery: = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-collection')
    const collection = Mongo.Collection.get(collectionName)
  }
})
```

References

https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/mongo-collection-instances

http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Event-Maps

Comment: The reason why I avoided doing it the way your explained in your answer is to avoid the redundant typing for may templates and each has many input elements.

Comment: You can use Template.body to attach global events